# Wish + Simple Past or Would?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, past-simple, wish

I've been struggling to know the difference, even though I've done research about it. Could you tell the difference between those 2?

Examples:

Why do we say:

> I wish *it'd stop raining*

And not:

> I wish *it stopped* raining

What would the difference be if I said either:

> I wish *this game would be good*
>
> I wish *this game were good*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The difference between these is actually not as hard as it seems, I think:

"would" indicates a hypothetical *future* thing:

> I wish it **would stop** raining.

(If my wish were true, then it *will* stop raining some time in the (presumably near) future.)

> I wish the game **would be** good.

(If my wish were true, then the game *will become* good, or *will end up being* good.)

In the context of the game, this might be said if, for example, somebody is releasing a new game but it hasn't come out yet, so you're waiting to see whether it will be good or not (but expressing this as a *wish* implies that you don't expect it actually will be good, or you're pretty sure it won't be).

On the other hand, past tenses are talking about a hypothetical *past* thing:

> I wish it **stopped** raining.
>   I wish it **had stopped** raining.

(If my wish were true, then the rain would have already stopped at some point in the past.)

For example, "I wish it had stopped raining yesterday, but it didn't, so I was stuck inside all day."

Note that you can use the *simple past* for this, but it is actually more common to use the *past perfect* ("had stopped") instead.

Now, the use of "were" in your last example, is actually talking about a hypothetical *present* thing:

> I wish this game **were** good.

(If my wish were true, then this game would be good *right now*.)

---

So, in summary, when expressing something hypothetical, like a wish, you are expressing your desire that:

- "would" -- something will happen in the future
- *past tenses* -- something did happen in the past
- "were" -- something is true right now